# I accidentally dropped my keyboard now its repeat rate is too high

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, repeat-rate

Basically , a few weeks ago i dropped my keyboard and now its not working properly i tried restarting the computer and other things but its not the computer its the keyboard i need help if anyone knows how to fix it I already tried changing the repeat delay and speed on the windows control panel and all of those other tips but i dont think its on the pc i think its the keyboard really , whenever i hold down a button it repeats at an unnormal amount like when i click backspace it almost removes a whole essay in 2 seconds , I dont know how to fix it and i need help because its making it really difficult to do homeworks and play games , heres a video link of the problem if you dont understand. https://www.loom.com/share/4a630b65e816418eb955de73790553ee

Comment: You have likely dislodged something inside the keyboard because of the drop. Replace the keyboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many variables in keyboard design, and it is EXTREMELY unlikely the board's component layout is published in a place you or I can access.

You're welcome to open the board and try to figure it out, but it is unlikely that, without extensive electronic and mechanical knowledge, you'll be able to solve the problem brought on by dropping the board.

TO CLARIFY BASED ON YOUR EDITED QUESTION: This is not the correct place to help you figure out how to find and repair the physical damage that has occurred to your keyboard. I don't know what the correct place is for that, but it isn't here. Keyboards are, rightly or wrongly, consumables these days. They are either too cheap to be worth the effort to repair, or too complex and unique for a random site on the internet to have the information necessary to help you determine the possible key components that need repair after you've damaged it.

I support your question being reopened, because this answer IS helpful information for others having the same problem, and the RIGHT answer isn't always the answer you WANT.